# How can I call a class method without the class?

Tags: ruby

I have a homework that has to accomplish something similar:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    yield
  end

  def helper (number)
    p number
  end
end

Foo.bar do 
  helper 5
end
```

Which of course gives an error, because 'helper' is not defined in Object. But in the task, it says straightforward that Foo has to be used this way:

```
Foo.bar do 
  helper 5
end
```

It does not say where 'helper' is defined though. How can I call this method like this above?

Answer (score 3):

Write code as below :

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    yield
  end
end

def helper (number)
  p number
end

Foo.bar do 
  helper 5
end
```

Put the method `helper` on the top level. Then `helper` will become a private instance method of the class `Object`. You are passing a block to the call `Foo.bar`, and block being a closure, have the access to its surroundings. So `helper 5` will called implicitly by `main`, *top level `Object` class instance*. Now the code will work.

Another way is using [`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include) method in the top level to include the `Foo` module to the class `Object`.

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    yield
  end

  def helper (number)
    p number
  end
end

# this will make available `helper` method as an instance method to the Object class.
include Foo 

Foo.bar do 
  helper 5
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`instance_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) to evaluate the block in the context of your object. Something like this:

```
class Foo
  def bar(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def helper(number)
    p number
  end
end

Foo.new.bar do
  helper 5
end
```

You could also make `bar` a class method and call:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar(&block)
    new.instance_eval(&block)
  end
  # ...
end

Foo.bar { helper 5 }
```

Or returning the instance:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar(&block)
    new.tap { |foo| foo.instance_eval(&block) }
  end
  # ...
end

foo = Foo.bar { helper 5 }
```